# Retrieving the MSBuild content into an artifact? Directory 'D:\a\1\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, continuous-integration

I try to understand how this MSBuild command is working with Azure DevOps Pipeline in Yaml. I get this error:

[image]

Here is my MSBuild instruction in my Azure Pipeline project:

```
- task: MSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '**/Beper-EDI.sln'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArguments: # Optional
    clean: true
    #maximumCpuCount: false # Optional
    #restoreNugetPackages: false # Optional
    #logProjectEvents: false # Optional
    #createLogFile: false # Optional
    #logFileVerbosity: 'normal' # Optional. Options: quiet, minimal, normal, detailed,
```

The build is correct. I can build my project. Then I try to publish my artifact by using:

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    pathToPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

I can process the pipeline but at the end my artifact is empty.

[image]

During my build I can see that the bin/Release folder and obj/Release folder are created and code is compiled.:

```
Starting: MSBuild
==============================================================================
Task         : MSBuild
Description  : Build with MSBuild
Version      : 1.192.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/msbuild
==============================================================================
"D:\a\_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.192.2\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\vswhere.exe" -version [17.0,18.0) -latest -format json
"D:\a\_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.192.2\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\vswhere.exe" -version [17.0,18.0) -products Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.BuildTools -latest -format json
"D:\a\_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.192.2\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\vswhere.exe" -version [16.0,17.0) -latest -format json
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe" "D:\a\1\s\Beper-EDI.sln" /nologo /nr:false /dl:CentralLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.192.2\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=|SolutionDir=D:\a\1\s"*ForwardingLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.192.2\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"  /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Release" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_10aa52a5-54c3-4730-90df-e99d0388b1f5_build_50_0"
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.
Build started 12/30/2021 8:07:45 AM.
Project "D:\a\1\s\Beper-EDI.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
Project "D:\a\1\s\Beper-EDI.sln" (1) is building "D:\a\1\s\Nppg.Core.BusinessServices\Nppg.Core.BusinessServices.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "bin\Release\".
  Creating directory "obj\Release\".
Project "D:\a\1\s\Nppg.Core.BusinessServices\Nppg.Core.BusinessServices.csproj" (2) is building "D:\a\1\s\Nppg.Core.Reports\Nppg.Core.Reports.csproj" (3:2) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "bin\Release\".
  Creating directory "obj\Release\".
Project "D:\a\1\s\Nppg.Core.Reports\Nppg.Core.Reports.csproj" (3:2) is building "D:\a\1\s\Submodules\nppg-core\Nppg.Core\Nppg.Core.csproj" (5:3) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "bin\Release\".
  Creating directory "obj\Release\".
```

How can I make sure the system let me access my /Release folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Retrieving the MSBuild content into an artifact? Directory 'D:\a\1\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'

That because the source of the task `PublishBuildArtifacts` is `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`.

But the MSBuild task not generate the file in the `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` folder, so we need to copy the files from the output folder of the task MSBuild to the folder `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` by the copy task after MSBuild task:

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    Contents: '**\bin\release\**'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

Comment: Why this step is never mentioned in Azure DevOps library and is not part of the template?

Comment: And I still don't get it because now I have 2 published artifact after the CI process. One is build.SourceLabel and the other is my drop folder

Comment: Because the order of construction is not fixed, there is no deliberate requirement for which task must be required, and everything is chosen according to actual needs. You could use the .NET Desktop template.

Comment: @BastienVandamme, update your YAML file and build result, I will follow up.

Comment: It is working now. Thank you for your help. I checked your profile and would like to keep you as contact or be able to follow you as I have so many questions about MSBuild and DevOps.

Comment: @BastienVandamme, Glad to know that work for you, you could accept it as answer. I am happy to keep in touch with you. If you have any questions in the future, please post @ me I will check it if I have time. My current main support forum is not SO, but other engineers on this forum will be as willing to help as I do.